# How can I install and use ack library on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, ack

I have never used Perl, but I am really impressed by the [ack](http://www.betterthangrep.com), which I would like to use for source code searching, etc.

Can anyone guide me of how to make use of this excellent library on Windows?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Start by installing perl http://strawberryperl.com/

Install [App::Ack](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/ack-1.88/) by typing (in a windows command shell)

```
C:\>cpan App::Ack
```

And undoubtedly this will prove useful http://learn.perl.org/

Comment: Note that using strawberryperl's portable version the directory of strawberryperl must not include spaces, otherwise odd errors rise.

Comment: Protip: `cpanm(1)` is a lot easier to use than `cpan(1)`, and it's also available in Strawberry Perl.

Answer (score 38):

Not all the tests pass on all versions of Windows. You can most likely get 100% functionality from ack even if the install tests fail.  Here is the command to force installation if failing tests prevent a normal install:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "CPAN::Shell->force(qw(install App::Ack));"
```

Comment: Or save yourself a lot of typing with `cpanm -f App::Ack`.

Add `-n` to skip tests since they currently don't really pass anyway... Won't affect anything other than skipping them, saving you time, but also leaving you not knowing if they would have passed...

Comment: Thanks for the info that the tests don't pass, but the install is okay. I was looking for a tarball solution until I found this post, but this is much easier.

Answer (score 35):

If you already have msysgit installed, then you don't need to install Perl, because you already have a version. You just need to download [the standalone version of ack](http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone) and put it somewhere in your bash path<sup>1</sup>. You can then run ack from your msysgit bash prompt.

If you also want to be able to run ack from the Windows command prompt, then you will need to create a batch script somewhere in your Windows path<sup>2</sup> with the contents:

```
@"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\perl" C:\path\to\ack-standalone.pl %*
```

(You'll obviously need to edit the paths above to match your msysgit installation and where you placed the ack script.)

<sub>1: I just stuck mine in the mysysgit bin directory: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ack`. This isn't the most sensible location for it, but it works.

2: Again, I just created the file `ack.bat` in the msysgit bin directory `C:\Program File\Git\bin`.</sub>

Comment: I simply dropped `ack-standalone.pl` in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`, using the filename `ack` (without extension). After this, running `ack` from Git Bash worked. No batch files or modification to the path were required.

Comment: @Grilse Yes, I do say that in my answer, (although I guess I could have worded it more clearly). The batch files and path modification are necessary if you want the script to run from within Windows's Command Prompt. (Which, also, I could have explained better.)

Comment: Well, if you would edit your answer to word this more clearly, that'd be awesome!

Comment: @Grilse Done. (Better late than never!)

Answer (score 25):

If you have cygwin installed, you can simply download the standalone version.  Perl is installed with cygwin.  Here are the steps:

```
$ vim .bash_profile
```

Remove the comments from the lines:

```
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#  PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi
```

Load the changes:

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

Make a bin directory:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
```

Download ack (from the homepage):

```
$ curl https://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.22-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 ~/bin/ack
```

**Note:** you will have to manually install curl as it doesn't come with cygwin by default.

Comment: The lines you commented out in `.bash_profile` are the lines that check `~/bin` exists before adding it to the path. Since you create a bin directory, the checks can remain and it will work (and **should** remain, in case the bin directory is ever removed).

Comment: After cygwin is installed, all 3 lines are commented out. As I indicate, you should remove the comments. I'm not sure why the middle line was missing the comment symbol, but I've edited it and added it back.

Comment: Nice stand-alone file solution. Thanks for also giving the information about the `PATH` and `.bashrc`

Answer (score 20):

You should also run the following command to enable color highlights:
**cpan Win32::Console::ANSI**

Comment: This should be a comment, rather than an answer, since it's *not* an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing worked for me, until I went to the ack website and saw this.

[image]

And I ran the following command in cmd prompt:

```
choco install ack
```

Comment: I'm told I already have it installed, but am getting `bash: ack: command not found` when trying to run it in git bash / MINGW64. I don't know what any of these words mean and I miss linux

Answer (score 5):

I had to force cpan to install `App::Ack` since some of the tests didn't pass:

```
C:\> cpan
cpan> force install App::Ack
cpan> q
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you feel about installing pre-built binaries from open source projects, you might also consider The Silver Searcher (ag). It's ack-compatible and faster than ack. It's also available on Linux from the repositories in recent distros.

http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/the-silver-searcher-for-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

You can install ack via cpan:

install strawberry perl

run cmd as admin

install ack:

cpan> force install App::Ack

it should work from there, followed this guide: http://www.jeedo.net/how-to-install-ack-on-windows-10/

Worked without any hitches.