# how find all instances of a word occurring anywhere in a website

Tags: web-crawler

I want to make list of all the occurrences of a word in my web application.
Few places that I am already looking at are HTML pages, code files, database, uploaded documents, images, videos.
Please suggest me what other places I should look, where that word can occur. 
I know crawler can be used for this task, but if anyone had same experience in the past then please suggest some good automated tools that are available to find that word easily all over in the website.

Comment: It sounds like you have the files on your computer already? Your OS and/or web development application should already have such search functionality built in. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I have the access to all the files and database. Only I need to find out where that word is, using an automated tool without missing a single place. Is there any free tool available that can run on windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

Since the files are local, I don't think you need a crawler. You just need to search the files.

As I said in my comment, the OS itself should be able to find most occurrences.

The program [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) should be able to do what you want. It's written in Perl, so it's fully portable to Windows. Here's a [SO question about installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023710/how-can-i-install-and-use-ack-library-on-windows) on Windows. This will work for all your HTML files and source code.

Some caveats:

- I'm not sure how well this will work for the databases. It depends entirely on how the databases store the data. You should really look for a search tool for your specific database.
- I'm not sure what you mean by searching for the work in images and videos. Do you expect something that will automatically find any text in images/videos, and parse it? That kind of search capability doesn't really exist.
- "uploaded documents"... what kind of documents? Being able to find the word again depends entirely on how the document is encoded. If it stores things in plaintext, then ack will find it. If it's something like a Word document, then you will probably just need to search using Word, unless there is some specific tool for searching Word documents I've never heard of.

Comment: For database, I have made the Search queries.
For images and videos, I am going through them manually.
'Uploaded documents'(e.g. PDFs, Doc, xls, txt etc) and HTML pages  are my main concern. I also want to fully ensure that after change in files and HTML pages nothing get break e.g. a broken url due to change in anchor tag in HTML file.