# unavailable cpan in cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I have unsuccessfully tried to install Perl module in cygwin like in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483795/148405). I have got the following error:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
Can't locate CPAN.pm in @INC (you may need to install the CPAN module) (@INC   contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.22 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

How can I obtain `cpan` in my cygwin?

---

There are some additional details. Actually my purpose was to install `ack` like in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811317/148405). However, it didn't work. After installing I have got an error:

```
$ ack
Can't locate filetest.pm in @INC (you may need to install the filetest module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.22 /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.22 .) at /home/loom/bin/ack line 218.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/loom/bin/ack line 218.
```

The following was my trying to locate `cpan`

```
$ cpan
-bash: cpan: command not found

$ ll /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN.pm
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN.pm': No such file or directory

$ find /usr/ -name *.pm | grep CPAN
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Converter.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Feature.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/History.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Merge.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Prereqs.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Requirements.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Spec.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/Validator.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta/YAML.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Meta.pm
/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/Parse/CPAN/Meta.pm
```

Comment: That's odd...the [perl package](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/perl/perl-5.22.3-1) should install CPAN.pm in `/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN.pm`, which is in your `@INC`. What happens if you do `cpan Foo::Bar` (where Foo::Bar is the module you want to install)?

Comment: Thank you @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. I have expanded the question

Comment: TSIBN has already answered your question: It comes with the `perl-5.22.3-1` package. So (re)install that package!

Comment: @ikegami - Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling `perl` helped.

```
$ apt-cyg install perl
```

Comment: To use `apt-cyg`, you'd first have to [install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286337/how-to-install-apt-cyg-for-cygwin) as it isn't available in Cygwin normally.