# How to install dialog for windows to be available in mintty bash

Tags: windows, bash, dialog, cygwin, mintty

I want to install dialog package for windows to use it in scripts at mintty bash.

The dialog package => https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/dialog-src.html

Answer (score 0):

After you start cygwin's setup-x86_64 installation program, go to
`Interpreters`section , from there you can choose `dialog` package.

For command line install, see [how to install apt-cyg for Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286337/how-to-install-apt-cyg-for-cygwin)

Comment: is there any process from command line import options. it would be helpful if you guide me a tutorial how to do that.